# how to avoid repeated values retrieved from database?

Tags: python, django

I have two models. One model with name field and other with key skill field and a foreign key for model1. I have stored values to fields. When I search using the key skills, it should bring the names with the entered fields.When I search for c and c++ if the name contains both c and c++, when I retrieve names based on search the name is repeated twice. I don't want to be repeated.
models.py

```
class form1(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
class form2(models.Model):
    keyskills=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    na=models.ForeignKey(form1)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.keyskills,self.na
```

views.py

```
def add(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        na=request.POST.get('name1')
        k=request.POST.get('key1')
        v1=form1(name=na)
        v1.save()
        v2=k.split(",")
        for i in v2:
            if i:
                form2(keyskills=i,na_id=v1.id).save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/add')
    else:
        s=form2.objects.all()
        return render(request,"search.html",{'s':s})
def search(request):
    var=""
    arr=[]
    if request.method=='POST':
        s1=request.POST.get("input1")
        s1=s1.split(",")
        for i in s1:
            if i :
                arr+=form2.objects.filter(keyskills=i)
        var=arr
    return render(request,"searchresult.html",{'var1':var})
```

searchresult.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
{% for i in var1 %}

 <p>{{i.na.name}}</p><br>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="input1">
<input type="submit" value="search">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone guide me?.. thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to define your 'forms' as models?!

Comment: sorry I didn't get you

Comment: If I understand Alex correctly, he's suggesting that "form1" is not a good name for a model. It's potentially confusing and not very descriptive. 

Models should approximately correspond to database tables. Each should ideally correspond to some sort of real world entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a set rather than an array. It will avoid duplicate entries.

```
def search(request):

    from sets import Set

    var=""

    # create set object
    set = Set()

    if request.method=='POST':

        s1=request.POST.get("input1")
        s1=s1.split(",")

        for i in s1:

            if i :
                # |= is the set union operator                       
                set |= Set(form2.objects.filter(keyskills=i))

        # convert set back to list
        var=list(set)

    return render(request,"searchresult.html",{'var1':var})
```

The basic idea:

1. Create a set object
2. Perform a union operation with each search result into the set
3. Convert the set back to a list and send it to the template

On a side note, I agree with some of the comments in that "form1" is not a great name for a model.